# Solve the parametrics system

Tags: linear-algebra

For which value of parameters $a,$ and $b$ the given system
$$2ax-3by=12ab ; ax+by=ab$$
have 1 solution

My answers is: for $a,b\neq 0$ the given system have only one solution which is

$x=3b,$ $y=-2a$
but I do not know whether I have done well. Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your solution is correct. We can see this by direct calculation. Since $a\neq 0$ we can write $x=(ab-by)/a$. Substituting this into the first equation gives $y=-2a$, and hence $x=3b$. In the other case we have $a=0$. Then, for $b\neq 0$ we obtain $y=0$, and $x$ arbitrary.